# How to upgrade Magento-CE-2.2.10 to Magento-CE-2.3.3 using Composer?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, magento-upgrade, command

I have magento 2.2.10 CE. I want to upgrade 2.2.10 to 2.3.3 CE with commands only. Does anyone know how to upgrade it with commands? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow Follow This Step :-**

[Command-line upgrade](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)